# getting VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED error

Tags: amd-graphics, vulkan

I wanted to start with vulkan, but I'm getting following error when I type `vulkaninfo`

```
=========== VULKAN INFO ===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.70

/build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

**HARDWARE**

Notebook model: Lenovo G70-35

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: You sure [you have a supported](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver) card?

Comment: @DankyNanky I got AMD here, and I think my graphic card is supported (according to https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/vulkan)